# Creating executable COM as ATL project and use it in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, com, atl

Trying to create COM object in executable and use it in C# project:

**Creating COM in executable.**

Create using ATL project
[image]

[image]

Adding class:

[image]

[image]

Compiles and runs without problem.

**Trying to use in C# project and got failure.** Self-registration for project... failed.  What might be wrong? VS started as admin.

[image]

Comment: The toolbox requires an ActiveX control, there is no indication whatsoever that you actually created one.  Well, you didn't, it can't be an EXE project and the "ATL Simple Object Wizard" doesn't create one.  It isn't simple.  Use Project > Add Reference instead, the `new` statement in your code.  I would also very, *very* strongly recommend that you do not create an EXE server, they have many very sharp edges when you use them from managed code, the kind that will always cause profuse bleeding when COM is not understood well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a reference to the type library of the server in your C# project to be able to use it :

1. Right Click `References` in the solution explorer and click `Add a reference`
2. In references manager choose COM.
3. Select your type type library ( `ComTstLib` in your example )
4. In Solution Explorer, open the shortcut menu for the reference you just added, and then choose Properties.In the Properties window, make sure that the Embed Interop Types property is set to True. This causes Visual Studio to embed type information for COM types in your executables, eliminating the need to deploy primary interop assemblies with your app.

At deployment time, you just need to ensure that your com server is already installed on the client machine.

See also [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwawt96c(v=vs.110).aspx)